# OpenAPI - how to set a property as string or array, and if array abide by #ref

Tags: javascript, typescript, swagger, openapi

I have the below openapi spec piece:

```
 *           type:
 *             - string
 *             - array
 *           items:
 *             $ref: '#/components/schemas/objectType'
```

I have an input which might be an empty string or an array of objects.  When I generate the above model it gives me below type:

```
string | any[]
```

However, what I need is:

```
string | objectType[]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to make use of the `oneOf` property. Here's a small example doc that I think does what you're looing for.

note: `oneOf` is an array of objects each declaring a whole schema type, rather than an array of types adjacent to an `items` declaration as in your code. This nesting is important, and allows for expression of arbitrarily complex union types.

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.1
info:
  title: Test API
  version: 1.0.0
paths:
  /foo:
    get:
      responses:
        200:
          description: "OK"
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                oneOf:         # <--- create a union type
                - type: string # <--- string |
                - type: array  # <--- FooResponseObject[]
                  items:
                    $ref: "#/components/schemas/FooResponseObject"
components:
  schemas:
    FooResponseObject:
      type: object
      properties:
        id:
          type: string
        name:
          type: string
```